# Check whether a cell contains a function

Tags: excel

Is there an in-built function to check if a cell contains a function?

I'm aware of: `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(J15,E2))`

But, if `J15` is "=" then I'd assume it'd work, but it seems as though referencing a cell just references the value, not the actual text.

Comment: `=NOT(ISNA(FORMULATEXT(J15)))` Will return TRUE if the cell has a formula and FALSE if not.

Comment: @ScottCraner Out of curiosity is there an alternative to this for older Excel versions? I'm using Excel 2010 and `FORMULATEXT` is not a built-in function.

Comment: Bah....forget what I wrote just use `=ISFORMULA(J15)`

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 no, you would have to write a udf to do it.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 `Function ISFORMULA(rng as Range) As Boolean: ISFORMULA = rng.HasFormula: End Function`

Comment: @ScottCraner Sounds like a solution. Why not post it as such?

Comment: @Ralph because I am not sure that is what is being asked.  If I was I would post.